# I can't find a jar that has javax.sound.sampled

Tags: java, javax.sound.sampled

I'm trying to create an UDP voice chat by following an on-line tutorial that requires that I import javax.sound to my code. So I downloaded the javax lib from [Java2S](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxjar.htm), but I can't find javax.sound in the jar file, since it goes from javax.servlet to javax.xml.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I don't think anybody is willing to watch a video and then guess what you did or did not do... please [edit] your question and provide the details here, as text, as a [mcve]. There is also probably no `.sound` class anyway, as dots are not allowed in class names, and Java classes ususally start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Although being quite old, package javax.sound.sampled seem to be still present in Java SE 17. However, note that you will certainly need  additional libraries handling MP4, vorbis, opus or other compressed formats to make a voice chat, as the standard package only handles uncompressed formats like .wav, far too big for network uses.